# Win 8 App fails suspend cert when running from 'Project - Store' but passes when running WACK separately

Tags: windows-8, suspend

When I run the Windows App Cert Kit (WACK) against my 'Release' install of my app on my machine, all the tests pass fine, when I go to: Project -> Store -> Create App Packages... and run the WACK at the end of that, it always fails on the Performance Test, specifically the 'Suspend' process.

What is the difference?

Is it the same WACK version that is running in VS2012 RTM compared to the one started via the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same version of WACK. All "Project -> Store -> Create App Packages" does is run the kit on your application. My assumption would be that Visual Studio is causing your computer to run a bit sluggishly, and as such is causing the application to fail WACK while it's running. I've seen the same thing happen while running WACK in a Virtual Machine.

Is Visual Studio running when you run with a passing result? Are there any other differences on your system when you get the passed rating? My assumption would be that the application is fine with a passed rating, but if you submit it for certification and it fails because of Suspend/Resume, I'd inquire further.

Comment: I don't think it's the computer, when I run WACK independently, typically I have 4-5 instances of VS running at the same time.. This is the only difference I get, everything else passes.

However, I presumed along similar lines to you, that the problem is to do with VS, I submitted it, and it has just passed the Technical Compliance, so it seems ok